# Android NotificationCompact BigTextStyle not displayed

Tags: android, notifications, styles

I have a probelam with `NotificationCompact` `BigTextStyle`. I tried to implement this you bit of style but does not appear, you see only the title. The version of my Android is the `KITKAT`. I show you the code:

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder buildNotification(String title, String body, int page) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_small)
                    .setContentTitle(title);
    mBuilder = buildBigTextStyle(mBuilder, body);

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    resultIntent.putExtra("page", page);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    return mBuilder;
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder buildBigTextStyle(NotificationCompat.Builder builder, String body) {
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigTextStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    bigTextStyle = bigTextStyle.bigText(body);
    return builder.setStyle(bigTextStyle);
}
```

If I use the method setContentContext text appears correctly, just that you do not see everything.

**EDIT** : I tested on `LOLLIPOP` and higher version and it works properly. Only on KITKAT it does not work. Help me

**EDIT** : I have carried out tests on emulator with `KitKat` version is all working properly. I do not understand what could be the problem.

I hope someone can help me !!

Thank you

Comment: improved formatting